# How to solve a linear system inside Manipulate and use the result for Plot?

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate, dynamic

I typed a code for showing a plane and a line, and solve a system, but I can´t show the intersection, because I don´t know.

Here is a minimal working example for understanding my problem ( the real problem is here http://bit.ly/1SNxWJH  )

In this code I would like to show the solution of the system for the unknows (x,y):
a x + b y == c  AND    d x + e y == f
and plot it

at everytime, So if I move the slider of a,b,c,d,e,f  I would like to view/show the point (x,y) that is the solution of hte system

```
Manipulate[
 s = Solve[a x + b y == c && d x + e y == f];
 ListPlot[{s[[1, 1, 2]], s[[1, 2, 2]]}],
 Style[s, Bold],

 {a, 1, 10},
 {b, 2, 10},
 {c, 3, 10},
 {d, 2, 10},
 {e, 5, 10},
 {f, 8, 10}
 ]
```

I tried using `Dynamic@` and `DynamicModule`, but I have not a good result.

Comment: Do you want to solve the linear system for x and y? What do you wish to plot?

Comment: @bill-s .... I want to plot the solution

Comment: Mika, I'm afraid that I still don't understand. Could you explain exactly you consider to be "the solution" here? Have you seen the structure of the result returned by your `Solve` expression, and is that really what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{soln, pt},
  soln = Solve[
     a x + b y == c && d x + e y == f,
     {x, y}][[1]];
  Column[{
    StringForm["Intersection of lines: ``", soln],
    pt = {x, y} /. soln;
    ContourPlot[{a x + b y == c, d x + e y == f},
     {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
     Axes -> True,
     Epilog -> If[Length[pt] > 0,
       {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
        Tooltip[Point[pt], pt]}, {}],
     ImageSize -> Medium]}]],
 Row[{Control[{a, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
   Control[{b, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}],
 Row[{Control[{c, 3, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
   Control[{d, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}],
 Row[{Control[{e, 5, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
   Control[{f, 8, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: and How could I customize the TEXT in the Label, Supose that I want to view "SLOPE" instead a, or "RADIUS" instead b. I´m not used to use Control. I must learn. Thank you.

Comment: @MikaIke - as shown in the documentation -- just add a label, e.g., `Control[{{a, 1, "SLOPE"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: thank you. I looked for that, but I can´t view in the Help: http://www.iestrada.eu/snapshots/snap04hghg7.jpg

Comment: @MikaIke - look at the next to last entry in the table:  `{{u, Subscript[u, init], Subscript[u, lbl]}, ...}     include label Subscript[u, lbl]`

Comment: You´re right, thank you very much! for helping and instructing me.